# Can't see output on visual studio code

Tags: python

I cant see output in both terminal and output

Here is an example

[image: Here is an example]

Comment: Switch to the "OUTPUT" tab. Also, please post the code as text and not links to images. As a new contributor, you may want to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and enjoy the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: you have to type something, put a print as the first line, what you get back is a string not an int

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder i cant see my output in the ouput tab as well, sorry about wont do that again.

Comment: @awab, sorry, I didn't notice that you were not checking it properly. `input()` returns a string and not an integer, as @rio has stated. You can replace `if dw == 3:` with `if dw == "3":`.

Comment: Put something inside `input(...)` (ex. `input("Please input value: ")`) so you can see the prompt, and not just a blank/empty line which looks like nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this

```
dw = input("enter a value: ")

if dw=='3':
    print('Right!')
```

Then hit the triangular play button at the top right corner, switch to the TERMINAL tab.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered similar problems in vscode, the solution is to just press the delete icon on the terminal and run the code again

[image]

Comment: If you type 3 with that code, nothing gets printed. That's the problem